# fetch record form table and print in views.py django

Tags: python, django, database

I am creating a webpage in Django, Where I'm printing some lines using a table from DB. I need to fetch user click and perform separate action on each button dynamically.

Here is my home.html

```
<div>
    <table style="width:90%">
      {% for request_ in request_index %}
        <tr>
          <form method="POST" action="{% url 'Request_for_DB_1' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
          <td><b> Would you like {{ request_.id }} to give {{ request_.user_name }} permission? </b></td>
          <td>&nbsp; </td>
          
          <td><input style="background-color:#CFCFCF; color:blue" type="submit" value="Yes" name={{ request_.id }}></td>
          <td><input style="background-color:#CFCFCF; color:blue" type="submit" value="No" name={{ request_.id }}></td>
          </form>                  
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </table>
  </div>
```

Here is Views.py

```
def Request_for_DB_1(request):
    request_index = Permission_Request.objects.all()
    user_id = request_index.id
    current_user = request.POST.get('name')
    if user_id == current_user:
        clicked_user = "Condition is Correct... " 
    else:
        clicked_user = "Condition is Wrong... " 
    messages.info (request, clicked_user )
    return redirect('/')
```

By this view I am getting current_user  = None always
and this error

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'id'

The image of my table. Table name is "Permission_Request"

[image]

How to fix this issue?

Comment: You're literally getting `.all()` objects and then trying to get an `.id` from it. You should probably add that `id` to your URL or a form field that you can then read in `Request_for_DB_1`.

Comment: I suggest you work through the [the official django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/) to learn the fundamental concepts.

Comment: On a side note, why is the id for a `Permission_Request` called a `user_id`? Shouldn't it be `permission_request_id`? And what is a `Permission_Request` exactly? Does this name really describe what is stored in each row of the database table? I suggest trying to find names that accurately describe what the variable represents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I fix it
home.html

```
{% for request_ in request_index %}
                  <form method="POST" action="{% url 'Request_Accepted' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                     <td> <input style="background-color:#CFCFCF; color:blue" type="submit" value="Yes" name={{ request_.id }}> </td>
                </form>
                <form method="POST" action="{% url 'Request_Declined' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <td> <input style="background-color:#CFCFCF; color:blue" type="submit" value="No" name={{ request_.id }} > </td>
                </form>
{% endfor %}
```

in view.py

```
def Request_Accepted(request):
    for i in range(50):
        j = str(i)
        if j in request.POST:
            User_record = User.objects.get(id=j)
            User_record.is_permission_granted = True
            User_record.save()

            permission_records = Permission_Request.objects.get(id=j)
            permission_records.delete()
            
            clicked_user = "Permission granted. "
            messages.info (request, clicked_user )
            return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use .all() you get a query set.
Meaning all of the objects of permission model.

So you can’t use id because it’s a field of the model which you can do it only on one object.

So what you want to do is

```
request_index = Permission_Request.objects.get(<someFilter>)
```

Then you can use id or any other field in your model.

I’m assuming someFilter should be based on your request.
Maybe even send in the request the id and then get the model by it’s id.